# Spring Websocket and Stomp with RabbitMQ- Heartbeat listener/interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, stomp

I Have a Spring application with Websocket and Stomp and a cluster of RabbitMQ servers. The Websocket client is configured to send heartbeats and RabbitMQ responds alright. I keep a distributed cache of all the Websocket sessions between my servers, and update the cache when a connection is added or dropped. However, in the case of a server going down, or a connection being lost without the proper event being fired, all the disconnected connections on that server will stay in the cache with my current config. I was thinking of setting idle time on Hazelcast and somehow catch the heartbeat and do a contains/get on the cache to refresh the items. However, I cannot either catch the heartbeat in my controller with `@MessageMapping` or find a listener for heartbeat. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I wander if a `BrokerAvailabilityEvent` will work for you:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@code BrokerAvailabilityEvent}.
 *
 * @param brokerAvailable {@code true} if the broker is available, {@code}
 * false otherwise
 * @param source the component that is acting as the broker, or as a relay
 * for an external broker, that has changed availability. Must not be {@code
 * null}.
 */
public BrokerAvailabilityEvent(boolean brokerAvailable, Object source) {
```

Looks like it is emitted from the `StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.SystemSessionConnectionHandler.handleTcpConnectionFailure(String errorMessage, @Nullable Throwable ex)`.

Comment: I do not think it would. The point of interest here is Websocket connections into Springboot. If somehow I can intercept the heartbeat(ping pong between the client and the rabbitmq relayed through the stompBrokerRelay) then I can do a put/get/contains on my hazelcast distributed map to refresh that item in the cache.    And when the server goes down, just by not refreshing the items, they will be removed by Hazelcast. I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Basically, in a multi-server environment, how to keep track of my sessions in a distributed cache given the fact that a server can go down anytime without a chance to clean up the sockets connected to it from the cache...